# Azure OpenAI 'Bring Your Own Data' Feature Not Providing Correct Answers

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, openai-api, azure-openai

I've been using Azure's OpenAI and the 'Bring Your Own Data' (BYOD) feature for a while now. Recently, I've encountered an issue where the BYOD feature is not providing the correct answers to certain queries.

When I input the same question into the Azure Cognitive Search Explorer, it successfully returns the correct matches. However, when I pose the same question to the BYOD feature, it responds with "I don't have information about this."

I've double-checked my data and it seems to be correctly formatted and uploaded. I'm not sure why the BYOD feature isn't able to retrieve the correct information.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot and fix this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: refer this Azure [OpenAI](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ai-cognitive-services-blog/introducing-azure-openai-service-on-your-data-in-public-preview/ba-p/3847000) ['Bring Your Own`Data](https://blazorhelpwebsite.com/ViewBlogPost/8067#:~:text=Microsoft%20Azure%20OpenAI%20provides%20a%20service%20that%20will,%28but%20everything%20is%20imported%20into%20Azure%20Cognitive%20Search%29)

Comment: I had a similar problem, I solved it the first time by creating an indexer in cognitive search and update the index. This worked fine in one environment but did not in another. I would recommend you to write an script to pre-process the input files and split it in one-page chunks. There is a limitation in the number of prompt characters that may truncate the answers coming from cognitive search.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to try:

1. Did you turn on "Semantic Search" which will help with the results?
2. Sometimes asking the same question again will help get the correct answer.
3. You mentioned you run into the issue with "certain queries", did you notice some pattern of these queries?

Comment: If none of them helps, please contact to Microsoft Support and we can work with you to see your issue deeply

Comment: Yes, I have turned on Semantic Search. However, when I pose the same query multiple times, I often receive the response, "I can't find any information." 
 when I use the Azure Search Explorer with the same query, it provides the correct matching answer. Yet, when I use the same query bring your own data, it fails to deliver a response.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Marqo as your information source and pair it directly with GPT instead. This would give you a lot more control. Here's an example of augmented retrieval with BYOD on Marqo: https://www.marqo.ai/blog/from-iron-manual-to-ironman-augmenting-gpt-with-marqo-for-fast-editable-memory-to-enable-context-aware-question-answering

Answer (score 0):

I have a GitHub project that allows for integrating external data with LLM without the need for model retraining. It also enables a side-by-side comparison of Azure/OpenAI and GCP PaLM technologies. Check it out: https://github.com/joao8tunes/genai_music_chat